# NETWORKDAYS BUG?

Tags: google-sheets

It was fine yesterday~ It was fine in the past few years

The whole company was in trouble this morning

Simple NETWORKDAYS function, when counting the day to the current day, there is not a 1 but a 0

Jump directly to 2 from the day to the next day

Is this a BUG@@? It’s too weird

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETRSF.jpg
[image]

The same is true for other accounts, and the same is true for copying and pasting the original one.

The original good as long as the date is changed ~ it will jump to 0 days, and can't be changed back

Open the same spreadsheet on your phone and computer

The phone shows normal 1, the computer shows 0
[image]

EXCEL is normal

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtI63.jpg

[image]

Wondering if anyone is in the same situation?

Thanks for informing!

Comment: Welcome! Yes, I confirm - indeed `=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), TODAY())` returns 0, and `=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), TODAY()+1)` returns 2. (LibreOffice Calc for `=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), TODAY())` returns 1). This is indeed an error.

Answer (score 0):

The OP, and MANY others, submitted a issue to Google.

An unofficial workaround has been proposed by Mr Shane, a Google Silver Product Expert. The following is a direct quote.

---

As a (temporary) fix, people may like to consider the following:

Formula to overcome this problem and provide consistent calculation on both desktop and mobile devices:

If you want
1/8 and 1/8 = 0
1/8 and 2/8 = 1
Then use this formula:
=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1))

BUT, If you want
1/8 and 1/8 = 1
1/8 and 2/8 = 2
Then use this formula:
=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1))+1