# NETWORKDAYS.INTL Method Changed

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-docs, microsoft-excel

Google sheet's NETWORKDAYS.INTL Method supposes to calculate number of working days between two given dates, and consider weekends and holidays.
I use this method a lot in my functions, but today I noticed a change in the method, the formula used to return one when entering the same date for both start and end dates:

Example:

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2022,8,31),DATE(2022,8,31),"0000000")`

The formula above used to return 1 meaning there is one working days between August 31 and August 31, but not anymore!! as it returning 0 like the method days!

Anyone noticed that yet? and do you have a replacement for this method?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Another function with the [**same problem**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166331/networkdays-bug)

Comment: @JohnSUN hope they fix it soon.

Comment: I would also like to hope so, but I'm afraid it will not be soon. Firstly, I did not find a way to shout to the developers about this bug, and they themselves are unlikely to read our correspondence here. Secondly, this bug will need to be fixed in a way that does not break the many existing user tables that used these functions and made their own corrections to fix the bug - this can take a very long time.

Comment: I already reported it to them yesterday, but I don't believe they'll  respond soon,  Currently am using the solution from the link you shared, and it fixed my functions, but I have to keep observing it since they might fix it and reverse my work again.

Comment: @JohnSUN they fixed it!

Comment: Yes, I see - `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` now works correctly (as it does in other spreadsheet programs). But `=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), TODAY())` returns 0 as before.

Comment: @JohnSUN https://support.google.com/docs/thread/177159051/networkdays-bug?hl=en

Comment: Thanks @Sarah! Commentary Phillip Preston in that discussion pointed out MY mistake - of course today my formula returns 0 because today is not a working day. =NETWORKDAYS(TODAY()-4, TODAY()-4) returned 1. They actually fixed it very quickly.

Comment: @JohnSUN glad I helped!